# wide version of __FUNCTION__ on linux

Tags: widechar

is there a way i can print `__FUNCTION__` as a wide character on linux?

the trick with the WIDEN doesn't work for me, the gcc compiler prints:
 error: ?L_*FUNCTION*_? was not declared in this scope

any help?
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean WIDEN macro similar to the one from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3291047/how-do-i-print-the-string-which-file-expands-to-correctly/3291315#3291315

Comment: @VestniK: That only works for *VStudio*.

Answer (score 4):

7+ years later (although things seem to be the same) ...

Since you mentioned *gcc*, check [[GNU.GCC]: Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html) (**emphasis** is mine):

> C99 introduced __func__, and GCC has provided __FUNCTION__ for a long time. Both of these are strings containing the name of the current function (there are slight semantic differences; see the GCC manual). **Neither of them is a macro; the preprocessor does not know the name of the current function**.

Since ***__FUNCTION__*** is not a macro (the preprocessor doesn't "know" anything about it), it will remain untouched during (outer) macro expansion, generating at the end the `L__FUNCTION__` identifier, which is obviously invalid. 
That's why the *double macro* approach works for ***__FILE__*** (for example), but not for ***__FUNCTION__*** (or ***__func__***).

So, the short answer to your question is "**NO**" (at least **not** at preprocessor level). You will need to convert ***__FUNCTION__*** "manually" (e.g. using one of the [[man7]: MBSTOWCS(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mbstowcs.3.html) functions family).

**Note**: It works on *VStudio*, since according to [[MS.Docs]: Predefined Macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros) (**emphasis** still mine):

> - **__FUNCTION__** Defined as a string literal that contains the undecorated name of the enclosing function. The **macro** is defined only within a function.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done using macros, you just have to understand how macros expand.
To get a wide char version of the macro you need to create 2 layers of macros like so:

```
#define WIDE2(x) L##x
#define WIDECHAR(x) WIDE2(x)

#define WIDE_FUNCTION WIDECHAR(__FUNCTION__)
```

The all important piece is the `L##x` that appends the **L** character to the string constant before the compiler sees it. You can do this to `__FILE__` as well using the same technique.

Comment: Works in VS 2013, but not in GCC (only tired with v4.9.3).  Error msg:
StringMacros.h:16:18: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘L__FUNCTION__’
 #define WIDE2(x) L##x

Answer (score -3):

That looks more like a typo of `__FUNCTION__` than an issue with `widen()` or similar, at least if you pasted the exact error message.

Comment: __FUNCTION__    is a variable name instantiated by the compiler at each function in the code, this variable is being declared with ASCII representation (char*). hence, u cannot take this and convert to wide char without allocating a new wide character and copy into it using  wcscopy